# What is the equivalent of Scala groupBy in D?

Tags: d

Whenever you want to create a frequency `Map` in Scala, you can easily call `.groupBy` on a collection.

```scala
val seq = Seq("a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "a")
seq.groupBy(a => a) // Map(b -> List(b, b), a -> List(a, a, a), c -> List(c))
```

Same is easily done with nested collections.

```scala
val nseq = Seq(Seq("a", 1), Seq("a", -1), Seq("b", -5), Seq("c", 100), Seq("b", 5), Seq("a", 0))
nseq.groupBy(a => a(0)) // Map(b -> List(List(b, -5), List(b, 5)), a -> List(List(a, 1), List(a, -1), List(a, 0)), c -> List(List(c, 100)))
```

Notice how values get aggregated together for each key.

I tried to find analogous function in D and found `group`. It works somewhat differently since it returns tuple pairs.

```
int[] arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5];
arr.sort.group; // [Tuple!(int, uint)(1, 2), Tuple!(int, uint)(2, 4), Tuple!(int, uint)(3, 1), Tuple!(int, uint)(5, 1)]
arr.sort.group.assocArray; // [5:1, 3:1, 2:4, 1:2]
```

However, when it comes to nested collections.

```
Tuple!(string, int)[] arr = [tuple("a", 1), tuple("a", -1), tuple("b", 2), tuple("b", 25), tuple("c", 100), tuple("b", 21)];
arr.sort!("a[0] > b[0]").group!((a, b) => a[0] == b[0]); //(Tuple!(string, int)("c", 100), 1), (Tuple!(string, int)("b", 25), 3), (Tuple!(string, int)("a", 1), 2)]
```

The value aggregation does not happen and only the first value is taken. But what's the use of taking just one first value? One can of course circumvent this via

```
int[][string] res;
arr.each!(s => res[s[0]] ~= [s[1]]);
writeln(res) // ["c":[100], "a":[1, -1], "b":[25, 2, 21]]
```

but is it possible to this in one line without predefining `res` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Tuple!(string, int)[] arr = [tuple("a", 1), tuple("a", -1), tuple("b", 2), tuple("b", 25), tuple("c", 100), tuple("b", 21)];
> arr.sort!("a[0] > b[0]").group!((a, b) => a[0] == b[0]); // [Tuple!(string, int)("b", 25):3, Tuple!(string, int)("c", 100):1, Tuple!(string, int)("a", 1):2]
> ```

That's not the result I'm getting:

https://run.dlang.io/is/9lVPkv

It results in `[tuple(tuple("c", 100), 1), tuple(tuple("b", 25), 3), tuple(tuple("a", 1), 2)]`, which looks correct.

> but is it possible to this in one line without predefining `res` array?

I think you're looking for [`chunkBy`](https://dlang.org/library/std/algorithm/iteration/chunk_by.html):

```
arr.sort!("a[0] > b[0]").chunkBy!((a, b) => a[0] == b[0]).each!writeln;
```

This [results in](https://run.dlang.io/is/PP0914):

```
[Tuple!(string, int)("c", 100)]
[Tuple!(string, int)("b", 25), Tuple!(string, int)("b", 2), Tuple!(string, int)("b", 21)]
[Tuple!(string, int)("a", 1), Tuple!(string, int)("a", -1)]
```

Comment: "That's not the result I'm getting" -- I might have been copy pasting between several open tabs. Sorry for that.

Comment: It does not create an associative array with key and aggregated value though. But since `chunkBy` documentation refers to `groupBy` then this is as far as we can get in D I guess.

Comment: Phobos has `assocArray`, but not `assocArrayAccumulate` or such. Anyway, this is almost certainly more efficient as sorting and lazily returning slices does not require allocations.